# Browse through Sphinx results ignoring max_matches?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I wanted to use Sphinx to browse through a large amount of data (approx. 50 million rows). Apparently, with max_matches configuration set to 10,000, it can only allow me to browse up to 10,000 rows. If I increase the limit, it greatly slows down our server so as for now, the best amount for max_matches in our case is 10,000.

I'm using PHP API to access Sphinx and I need to make use of its functions like SetFilterRange(), SetFilter(), SetSortMode(), etc.

Now whenever I need to fetch data from Sphinx, this is how I do it:

```
// Some codes here to set filters
$sphinx->SetLimits( 100, 20 ); // Telling sphinx to return page 6
$results = $sphinx->query('');
```

This is OK, but when I try to browse over 10,000, it doesn't return anything. Is there a way to browse beyond 10,000 ignoring the limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [known behavior of Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-max-matches.html) (the CAVEAT EMPTOR part), read [this forum thread](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=5438).

One proposed workaround could be to set it to an astronomically big limit in your config, and decrease it dynamically when with SetLimits.

*copied out of the forum thread*:

```
$cl->SetLimits(($currentPage-1)*50, 50, max(1000,($currentPage*50)+100)) );
```

But the idea behind Sphinx is that you should be getting the good results for your query on the first pages therefore you doesn't want to read everything.

Comment: thanks.. the workaround is pretty tricky, I haven't really thought about that but I think it's a great idea.. this is already enough solution for me.. thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

What sort order are you using?

If its a defined sort order, like a timestamp, or even document id, then can redefine 'paging' to work as filters. Thereby not needing to use a high offset.

As you note high offers are evil. The only way they can be realised, is working out all the documents before the offset, and then discarding them. eg an offset of 100000, means 100000 rows must be calculated and then discarded. 
It pretty much negates being able to use indexes.